# Typescript Error: TS2451 Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node-dev

I'm building a NodeJS API using Typescript but ran into the error shown below.

Been on it for hours and all the solutions I've tried didn't work.

```
[ERROR] 22:49:39 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/services/orgService.ts:8:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'organization_1'.

8 const organization_1 = __importDefault(require("../model/organization"));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/routes/organization.ts:9:7
    9 const organization_1 = require("../controller/organization");
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'organization_1' was also declared here.
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "dist/",
    ".vscode"
  ]
}
```

Also, seems every time I change `target` and `lib` in `tsconfig` e.g. I get a different error.

Comment: We can't really help unless you show the code that the declarations and imports.

Comment: Initially included the code but SO complained that I have too much code in there